# How do I get onto my Liege's Council?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

How do I get my character (a count in this situation) get himself appointed to his liege's council? He has a higher stat than the current councilor.

Comment: Have you tried assassinating the current councillor?

Comment: You could set it as your ambition. I don't know if that triggers some events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way. The key factors are:

- set as ambition
- improve certain skill, related to the councilor position
- be in good relations with the liege OR
- pose a threat to the liege as a faction member. But make sure that the liege just cannot smash you and strip of your titles)

Comment: "Creating" vacancies definitely increases your chances. Having high intrigue, taking the intrigue focus to spy on the current councilor, and using your own chancellor to sow dissent can all help (or backfire horribly). This happens all the time since they made Commander into a special minor title. I don't recommend accepting an offer for that or Marshal; something about fighting in the AI's wars makes people die all the time.